# SVG Rendering problem - Firefox cuts off the sibling SVG elements - is there a workaround?

Tags: html, svg, firefox

```html
<div>
  <svg id="svg_viewport"
width="800" height="800"
style="background-color: pink"
>
 <svg id="o_1"
   x="10" y="10" width="200" height="200"
   >
   <image href="https://www.1kfa.com/table/img/image.png"
     height="200" width="200"></image>
 </svg>
 <svg id="o_2"
   x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100"
   >
   <rect id="r_2"
     width="100" height="100"
     fill="green"
     ></rect>
 </svg>
  </svg>
</div>
```

This works in Chromium, but in Firefox, the green rect gets cut off.  It's like the browser is rendering it "inside" the image of svg `o_1`.

Has anyone faced this before?  Workarounds?

Comment: I'm seeing the fault here in FF 84.0.1. The green square is being clipped to the bounds of the preceding child SVG.  I've filed a bug report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1684625

Comment: Robert, the green square should go all the way to the leftmost edge of the pink background.  For me, it doesn't.

Comment: This issue will disappear in Firefox 86. I've disabled the failing codepath and checked in tests so that if and when that codepath is enabled the issues it causes would need to have been fixed.

Comment: sounds good.  did the codepath actually provide any feature?

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a workaround.

By adding a `viewBox`, Firefox decides to render it properly.  See line 8:

```html
<div>
  <svg id="svg_viewport"
    width="800" height="800"
    style="background-color: pink"
    >
     <svg id="o_1"
       x="10" y="10" width="200" height="200"
       viewBox="0 0 200 200"
       >
       <image href="https://www.1kfa.com/table/img/image.png"
         height="200" width="200"></image>
     </svg>
     <svg id="o_2"
       x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100"
       >
       <rect id="r_2"
         width="100" height="100"
         fill="green"
         ></rect>
     </svg>
  </svg>
</div>
```